# Batch file - how to read first token of a string delimited by a space

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, tokenize

Using batch script, I want to get a first token of a line delimited by a space.
Can this be done without a for loop?

```
example input: a b c d
example output: a
```

Thanks.

Comment: You would always need a for loop I think, even if you did not use tokens= but a substring you would still need a for to calculate the position of the space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the text as a batch parameter using `CALL` command like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set text=a b c d
set result=
call :getFirstParam %text%
echo %result%
goto :eof
:getFirstParam
set result=%1
goto :eof
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use AWK this way:

```
awk '{print $1}' <your_file>
```

Comment: This question is specific to the use of batch files under Windows. `awk` is not a built-in command in Windows or batch files.